# how can I access to another column in blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have the id in a blade and I want to access to another column.
I have $article->country_id which gives access to the id of the foreign key **country**.
How can I find the record using id and then get access to country->name.
I have done the things below but it doesn't work as I have explained.

**Here is the blade**

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
<div class="col-md-12">
کشور:<h4 class ="post-title">{{route('article.whichCountry',$article->country_id)}}</h4>
</div>
@endforeach
```

here is **web.php**

```
Route::get('article/whichCountry/{country}',[
    'uses' => 'ArticleController@whichCountry',
    'as' => 'article.whichCountry'
]);
```

and here is **whichCountry in ArticleController**

```
public function whichCountry($id){
        $country = country::where('id',$id)->first();
        return $country->name;
    }
```

The point is that it doesn't call the function *whichCountry*
and prints:
**http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/whichCountry/10**

Thank you very much for your response in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your route access needs to be like below, giving value for `{country}` parameter.

```
{{ route('article.whichCountry',['country' => $article->country_id]) }}
```

Second, instead of `where` in your controller method, **if** Id is the primary key, you can just do:

```
Country::find($country);
```

Also, change your function definition like below for the parameter value filling

```
public function whichCountry($country){
```

Comment: @saeeddoozandeh I have updated my answer. If it still doesn't reach there, I will need more details to debug. Does `php artisan cache:clear` help?

Comment: why does it just show the address like this? http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/whichCountry/10
What should be done to show the returned value of the function?

Comment: I think I should not call the function like this: {{......}}

Comment: @saeeddoozandeh The link generated is correct. I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work? What error does it give? Does this happen with any new routes you create?

Comment: There are no errors but I want to see the value not the link
As I have written in the function, I need to have $country->name so I want to see the name of the country.
What should be done?

Comment: You should see the value along with the link but you need to elaborate more. Did you change any . htaccess or any php . ini setting for this Laravel project? Does this happen only with this route or you find issues with all the other routes?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to implement this. First check your `Controller` is getting the id properly. Then use `find` method

Your route should be like this

```
{{route('article.whichCountry',['id'=>$article->country_id])}}
```

And in your controller you have to use like this

```
public function whichCountry($id){
    $country = country::where('id',$id)->first();
    return $country->name;
}
```

In your **web.php** looks like this

```
Route::get('article/whichCountry/{id}',[
    'uses' => 'ArticleController@whichCountry',
    'as' => 'article.whichCountry'
]);
```